# Pandoc Markdown Generator is generating strangely indented code

Tags: pandoc

Im using pandoc@0.2.0 with node and the following command

`pandoc -f markdown -t html5 -o test.html test.md`

My starting markup is

````
## Code Example

This example shows how to invoke the about dialog on demand, passing in some content, version info and the product name and product line.

```javascript
$('body').about({
    appName: 'My App Name',
    productName: 'My Product line',
    version: 'ver. 1.0.0',
    content: '<p>Fashionable application for fashionable customers.</p>'
});
```
````

However, the problem is that this renders like this:

```
$('body').about({
         appName: 'My App Name',
         productName: 'My Product line',
         version: 'ver. 1.0.0',
         content: '<p>Fashionable application for fashionable customers.</p>'
       });
```

Is there a trick i can use to make it render like this?

```
$('body').about({
  appName: 'My App Name',
  productName: 'My Product line',
  version: 'ver. 1.0.0',
  content: '<p>Fashionable application for fashionable customers.</p>'
});
```

The problem seems to be the user of whitespace / tabs. Its adding extra tab characters in. Is there some way to control that? Here is the generated html

```
<code class="sourceCode javascript">
        <span class="fu">$</span>(<span class="st">'body'</span>).<span class="fu">about</span>({
          <span class="dt">appName</span>: <span class="st">'My App Name'</span>,
          <span class="dt">productName</span>: <span class="st">'My Product line'</span>,
          <span class="dt">version</span>: <span class="st">'ver. 1.0.0'</span>,
          <span class="dt">content</span>: <span class="st">'&lt;p&gt;Fashionable application for fashionable customers.&lt;/p&gt;'</span>
        });
        </code>
```

Comment: you should probably post the generated html instead of a screenshot, and try to replicate this with the command line pandoc...

Comment: thanks that did help some as i can see its adding additional tab characters/whitespace.

Answer (score 3):

I'm running into the same issue. Basically, the issue seems to be that pandoc at some point started indenting things inside the pre block; which looks like a bug to me in their pretty printing logic.

I fixed it with two ugly sed commands:

```sh
  pandoc --from markdown+smart+yaml_metadata_block+auto_identifiers \
        "foo.md" \
        -o "foo.html" 

  # pandoc indenting causing issues, so remove it
  sed -i 's/^\s*<span/<span/g' "foo.html"
  sed -i 's/^\s*\([^<]\)/\1/g' "foo.html"
```